# Search for "Role name" in automation

Tags: query, data, visual-flows

How do I use Workbench (or another tool) to query for Role Name. I have to update role names and I am trying to determine if any role names are hardcoded in any existing flows, process builder, workflows, validation rules, etc.

Comment: Just search for the string value of the role name in all metadata types using your IDE

Comment: Thanks, that works!!!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to use your IDE like VsCode or Illuminated Cloud.
Be sure your project contains all the metadata types where UserRole values are used in expressions:

- Apex classes and triggers
- Aura
- LWC
- Visualforce components and pages
- Workflows
- Process Builder
- Flows
- Groups
- Custom Objects
- Sharing Rules
- Reports
- ... (I'm probably forgetting a few)

Then use the IDE's global search feature across all project files to search for the role name.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have experience with any IDE, but I can ask a developer for help.